# Monomorphism of schemes which is not a an open or closed immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have showed that every open/closed immersion of schemes is a monomorphism of schemes, but I know that the converse is not true, i.e., not every monomorphism of schemes is an open/closed immersion.
However, I have not been able to find an counterexample. Does anyone know a monomorphism of schemes that is not a composition of open or closed immersions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another instructive example: $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: That is an open immersion, right?

Comment: @Andarrkor No, the single point in $Spec(\mathbb{Q})$ is sent to the generic point of $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$. The generic point is not open.

Answer (score 1):

As a composition of two monomorphisms is a monomorphism, you can take the composition of an open and a closed immersion. For example
$$\mathbb A^1 \setminus \{0\} \hookrightarrow \mathbb A^2, x \mapsto (x,0).$$

Comment: What I meant that it is not a composition of open/closed immersions, sorry. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Example 1: Let $X$ be the curve obtained by gluing the points $0$ with $\infty$ in $\mathbb{P}^1$.
We have a natural normalization morphism $f: \mathbb{P}^1\to X$.
The restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$, which we call $g: \mathbb{A}^1\to X$ is a monomorphism of schemes:

Indeed, for any point $x\in X,$ we have that the fiber $g_x: \mathbb{A}^1\times_X x\to x$ is an isomorphism.
Thus, by [05VH](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05VH), we have that $g$ is a monomorphism.

In this example, $g$ is an open immersion followed by a normalization morphism, not a closed immersion.

Example 2:
Consider $0\coprod \mathbb{G}_m\to \mathbb{A}^1.$
By the same reasoning as above, we see that this morphism is also a monomorphism.
It is a union of closed and open immersions, but not a composition of them.